# Get accurate Rotation Angle in Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make a program in Unity simulating a boats movement. This includes what happens when the boat collides with something. While the boat moves just fine, the heading values that I returns aren't in radians or degrees. Here is the code I am using to determine the Heading:

```
  void getHdg()
  {
    float temp = this.transform.rotation.z;

    craft.ChangeHeading(temp);
  }
```

Every site that I went to suggested the use of **Euler Angles**, but from what I saw, they only update on a key press.

I need a way to either:

- update the heading whenever the boat turns *(even on collisions with other objects)*
- or transform the bogus vaules from the **transform.rotation** code to degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two issues with the code:

1. The code is checking for the z axis, not the y
2. the need to test for **Euler Angles** which do constantly update

Here is the correct code:

```
void getHdg()
{
    float temp = this.transform.eulerAngles.y;
    craft.ChangeHeading(temp);
}
```